# Merging/Intersecting tables in matlab

Tags: matlab

MATLAB: How can I intersect two tables to get one table with a column where approximate (very close or exact) values from two columns are merged? The tables were generated from a sensor and a robot whose frequencies are not the same. The related column to both of them is the Timestamp which I need to only pick table values from those Timestamps in both tables which are very close or exact 
 I attached a screenshot of the tables generated in my workspace and the kind of result I need at the end for reference purpose

For the two tables as generated, open [RAWTABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI23j.jpg)

For a sorted table from the two how the final result should be, open [COMBINED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FZs6.jpg) and check the two tables, the one at the top just shows how the tables are sorted based on the Timestamps, while the one below shows the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [interp1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function to interpolate one so that they have the same sampling frequency. Assuming `oldTimestamps` are the timestamps from the sensor to be changed, `oldValues` are the associated sensor readings, and `newTimeStamps` is an array of the timestamps of the other sensor, you could enter:

```
newValues = interp1(oldTimestamps, oldValues, newTimeStamps);
```

Comment: Thank you, although I have solved it in another way. I will still try this and see if it improves the speed